# Numerical problems with high dimensional multivariate normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, high-dimensional

Is there a way around the numerical problem of calculating the denominator of the Multivariate Gaussian distribution of high dimensional vectors?
Given the following formula $$f_{\mathbf X}(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = \frac{\exp\left(-\frac 1 2 ({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})^\mathrm{T}{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})\right)}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}$$
With a feature vector of size, $>128$ the denominator cannot be computed with normal precision(64 bit) frameworks.
My feature vectors are $1024$ long, and I haven't found a way to come across the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to operate on log domain in such cases. There are implementations (employing factorizations like Cholesky, LU) available in common languages:

- python: [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.slogdet.html?highlight=logdet#numpy.linalg.slogdet), [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/logdet)
- R: [msos](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/msos/versions/1.1.1/topics/logdet), [lme4](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/0.5-2/topics/logDet)